# Pandas drop rows in consecutive time range and with same pair of features

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I have a dataset that looks like this:

|  | id1 | id2 | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 56 | 99 | 2007-04-06 15:49:21 |
| 1 | 56 | 104 | 2007-04-06 18:26:13 |
| 2 | 56 | 104 | 2007-04-13 11:27:52 |
| 3 | 56 | 104 | 2007-04-13 11:28:41 |
| 4 | 56 | 104 | 2007-04-13 11:28:52 |
| 5 | 56 | 104 | 2007-04-13 11:33:25 |
| 6 | 56 | 104 | 2007-04-13 14:35:52 |
| 7 | 104 | 56 | 2007-04-13 11:28:23 |
| 8 | 104 | 56 | 2007-04-13 11:29:46 |
| 9 | 128 | 105 | 2007-03-27 18:39:45 |
| 10 | 217 | 256 | 2007-03-29 14:55:57 |

I would like to drop all observation where for the same pair of IDs the time value is within 5 minutes of the previous row. It also should be "rolling" meaning if there are three observation where the second is 4 minutes from the first and the third is 4 minutes from the second, I only keep the first row. Also it doesn't matter if an Id is in the id1 or Id2 column.

So the output of the dataframe above should be:

|  | id1 | id2 | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 56 | 99 | 2007-04-06 15:49:21 |
| 1 | 56 | 104 | 2007-04-06 18:26:13 |
| 2 | 56 | 104 | 2007-04-13 11:27:52 |
| 3 | 56 | 104 | 2007-04-13 14:35:52 |
| 4 | 128 | 105 | 2007-03-27 18:39:45 |
| 5 | 217 | 256 | 2007-03-29 14:55:57 |

The best I could come-up is:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df['time'].iloc[i] <= df['time'].iloc[i-1] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=5):
        df = df.drop(i)
        df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    else:
        continue
```

but: 1. it raises an indexer is out-of-bounds error. 2. It doesn't "roll". 3. It distinguishes if an id is in the id1 or id2 column.

Thank you in advance with your help!

Comment: Is your example output correct? I think entry with index 3 should be in the result, since it's more than 5 min later than entry 2.

Comment: Hi, you're right! thanks for letting me notice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
m = df.groupby(['id1', 'id2'], as_index=False)['time'].transform(lambda g: g.diff()).le(pd.Timedelta(minutes=5))['time']
df = df.loc[~(m | m.shift(-1))]
```

Step by step introduction:

You can group by `id1` and `id2` columns and diff the `time` column

```py
diff = df.groupby(['id1', 'id2'], as_index=False)['time'].transform(lambda g: g.diff())
```

```
print(diff)

              time
0              NaT
1              NaT
2  6 days 16:55:39
3  0 days 00:06:49
4  0 days 00:00:11
5  0 days 00:05:33
6  0 days 03:01:27
7              NaT
8  0 days 00:01:23
9              NaT
10             NaT
```

Then compare it with 5 minutes

```py
m = diff.le(pd.Timedelta(minutes=5))
```

```
print(m)

     time
0   False
1   False
2   False
3   False
4    True
5   False
6   False
7   False
8    True
9   False
10  False
```

And convert the previous row to True

```py
m = m | m.shift(-1)
```

```
print(m)

     time
0   False
1   False
2   False
3    True
4    True
5   False
6   False
7    True
8    True
9   False
10  False
```

At last, use booleaning indexing to select the False row

```py
df = df.loc[~m['time']]
```

```
print(df)

    id1  id2                time
0    56   99 2007-04-06 15:49:21
1    56  104 2007-04-06 18:26:13
2    56  104 2007-04-13 11:21:52
5    56  104 2007-04-13 11:34:25
6    56  104 2007-04-13 14:35:52
9   128  105 2007-03-27 18:39:45
10  217  256 2007-03-29 14:55:57
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `groupby` and `diff`:

```
MIN_LIMIT = 5

def remove_duplicated_entries(df):
    time_diff = df['time'].diff()
    return df[(time_diff.dt.seconds > MIN_LIMIT*60) | (time_diff.isna())]

# Created to sort ids to ignore the order in the groupby. You can reuse id1 and id2 instead if you don't care.
df[['id_min', 'id_max']] = np.sort(df[['id1', 'id2']], axis=1)
clean_df = df.sort_values('time').groupby(['id_min', 'id_max'], as_index=False).apply(remove_duplicated_entries).reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns=['id_min', 'id_max'])
```

Which results in:

```
   id1  id2                time
0   56   99 2007-04-06 15:49:21
1   56  104 2007-04-06 18:26:13
2   56  104 2007-04-13 11:27:52
3   56  104 2007-04-13 11:34:25
4   56  104 2007-04-13 14:35:52
5  128  105 2007-03-27 18:39:45
6  217  256 2007-03-29 14:55:57
```

Please note that using `diff` assumes the `time` column is sorted in ascending order (hence the `sort_values` to make sure it is the case).

**EDIT after discussion (see comments):**
The following test set breaks the answer from @Ynjxsjmh too (note the new items at the end):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 128, 217, 104, 104], 
                   'id2':[99, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 256, 56, 56],
                   'time': pd.to_datetime(['2007-04-06 15:49:21', '2007-04-06 18:26:13', '2007-04-13 11:27:52', '2007-04-13 11:28:41',
                            '2007-04-13 11:28:52', '2007-04-13 11:34:25', '2007-04-13 14:35:52', 
                            '2007-03-27 18:39:45', '2007-03-29 14:55:57', '2007-04-13 11:34:35', '2007-04-13 14:36:35'])})
```

The result with their answer is:

```
    id1  id2                time
0    56   99 2007-04-06 15:49:21
1    56  104 2007-04-06 18:26:13
5    56  104 2007-04-13 11:34:25
6    56  104 2007-04-13 14:35:52
7   128  105 2007-03-27 18:39:45
8   217  256 2007-03-29 14:55:57
9   104   56 2007-04-13 11:34:35
10  104   56 2007-04-13 14:36:35
```

Comment: The only issue with this solution is that it also keeps observation with index 7, which should not be kept because it falls in the range of observations 2-5, just with the IDs swapped.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that requirement! However, then I think the answer from @Ynjxsjmh has the same problem. I edited my answer with an example dataset that breaks with that solution, too. I will update my answer to fix it. With the other data it was working by "accident" due to the shifting on the mask. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Alright, I edited the answer, in principle you can use the same solution (the new sorted columns) for the answer from @Ynjxsjmh, too!